# Crystal Report CSV Generation

Tags: c#, csv, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-8.5

I have a Crystal Report file to generate **PDF** and **CSV** formatted files. I can able to generate report in the pdf format successfully. But It generates misaligned file content when I try to generate **CSV**. We have 2 grouping for the report file. That grouping fields are showing like misaligned only for the **CSV** generation. (csv is vied in excel).

Any idea why this is happening?

Crystal Report version: *13.0.2000.0*
[image]

Comment: Hmm, maybe check the  "Isolate report/page sections" in the export options for that section.


Check this [SAP Support Link](https://apps.support.sap.com/sap/support/knowledge/public/en/1198296)

Comment: May you post the design?